# Movieclip not orbiting correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm current a student doing a flash animation. I'm new to it and algorithms.
The problem with my current project is that the movieclip I'm animating is not orbiting correctly, I followed the video properly, and the Moon, Earth, Sun thing works. However using that particular set of codes, I applied to my project, but it seems that the center is way off from my desired center.

Video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO2YvR1r-Bo

The bottom code is called by using a timer instead of ENTER_FRAME

```
    function rocketMoving(){
var earthGravityX:Number = earth.x + (earth.width * .5) / 2; 
var earthGravityY:Number = earth.y + (earth.height * .5) / 2;
    sinrocket += .001; 
    cosrocket += .001; 
    rocket.x = Math.sin(sinrocket * orbitSpeed1) * earthOrbitDiameter - earthGravityX ; 
    rocket.y = Math.cos(cosrocket * orbitSpeed1) * earthOrbitDiameter - earthGravityY ;
    rocket.rotation = (Math.atan2(rocket.y-earth.y, rocket.x-earth.x) * 180 / Math.PI);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've set your registration point wrong.

At 3:00 in the video you mentioned, he sets the registration point for the sun to be top left.
He also sets the registration point for the earth to top left, and he sets the sets the registration point of the moon to the top left.

So be sure those are the same.

Looking at your code...

```
var earthGravityX:Number = earth.x + (earth.width * .5) / 2; 
var earthGravityY:Number = earth.y + (earth.height * .5) / 2;
```

Beware of order of operations here!

Going by the idea that earth has top left as registration point, and earth is at 100,100, with a size of 10x10...

```
var earthGravityX:Number = 100 + (10 * .5) / 2;//earth.x + (earth.width * .5) / 2; 
var earthGravityY:Number = 100 + (10 * .5) / 2;//earth.y + (earth.height * .5) / 2;
```

Turns into...

```
var earthGravityX:Number = 100 + 5 / 2;//earth.x + (earth.width * .5) / 2; 
var earthGravityY:Number = 100 + 5 / 2;//earth.y + (earth.height * .5) / 2;

var earthGravityX:Number = 100 + 2.5;//earth.x + (earth.width * .5) / 2; 
var earthGravityY:Number = 100 + 2.5;//earth.y + (earth.height * .5) / 2;
```

equals 102.5. That's off center.
I can't find the correct order of operations for you, however. Halving the earth's width and adding it to the X gets you the center... but what's the division by 2 for?

What happens if you remove the division?